# Django Rest - "<ClientProfile: mike@tyson.com>" needs to have a value for field "clientprofile" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement an API where I can:

- Return all ClientProfile objects, with a nested ManytoMany field containing a list of Location objects (I don't really care if it's PK or actual object, actual object would be nice.)
- Be able to POST a ClientProfile object, and specify which Location objects should be associated with it using the PK of the Location object, like so:

  ```
          {
          "user": {
              "email": "mike@tyson.com"
          },
          "first_name": "Mike",
          "last_name": "Tyson",
          "locations": [
              1,5,21

          ]
      }
  ```
- I have seen people saying "You need to implement a save method" for normal Django. I'm new to Django and Django REST, so not sure where or how to implement a solution for this..

Please save me from this nightmare!

Pip Freeze Output:

```
appdirs==1.4.0
chardet==2.3.0
Django==1.10.5
django-csvimport==2.5
djangorestframework==3.5.4
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.1.10
six==1.10.0
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/project/userauth/tests/User.py", line 28, in setUp
    self.response = self.client.post(path="/client-profile/", format="json", data=self.data)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 290, in post
    path, data=data, format=format, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 212, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 409, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 279, in request
    return super(APIClient, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 231, in request
    request = super(APIRequestFactory, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 494, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/project/userauth/views/ClientProfile.py", line 25, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/venv/project/userauth/serializers/ClientProfile.py", line 20, in create
    client_profile = ClientProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 397, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 550, in __init__
    setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 499, in __set__
    manager = self.__get__(instance)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 476, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 783, in __init__
    (instance, self.source_field_name))
ValueError: "<ClientProfile: mike@tyson.com>" needs to have a value for field "clientprofile" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Models:

```
class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_profile')
    enabled = models.BooleanField(_('Enabled?'), default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, related_name='client_profile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email


class Location(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

Serializers:

```
class ClientProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)
    locations = LocationSerializer(required=False, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ClientProfile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'locations')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(email=user_data['email'], is_client=True)
        client_profile = ClientProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)

        return client_profile


class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id', 'company', 'display_name', 'address1', 'address2',
                  'city', 'county', 'postcode', 'country', 'tel', 'email')
```

Views:

```
class ClientProfileList(APIView):
    """
    List all ClientProfiles, or create a new ClientProfile.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if self.request.user.is_client:
            client_profiles = ClientProfile.objects.all()
            serializer = ClientProfileSerializer(client_profiles, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ClientProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class ClientProfileDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a ClientProfile instance.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return ClientProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except ClientProfile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        client_profile = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ClientProfileSerializer(client_profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        client_profile = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ClientProfileSerializer(client_profile, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        client_profile = self.get_object(pk)
        client_profile.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
class LocationList(APIView):
    """
    List all Locations, or create a new Location.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if self.request.user.is_client:
                locations = Location.objects.all()
                serializer = LocationSerializer(locations, many=True)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class LocationDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a Location instance.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Location.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Location.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        location = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = LocationSerializer(location)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        location = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = LocationSerializer(location, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        location = self.get_object(pk)
        location.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django Models with `ManyToMany` fields **must be saved before you can add related instances**. (To add an entry in the ManyToMany relation, Django needs the parent model instance pk which is set only after the model is created.)

So your ClientProfile must be saved before you can add any related Location instance.

To fix this error, just update your `ClientProfileSerializer.create` method:

```
class ClientProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(email=user_data['email'], is_client=True)
        locations = validated_data.pop('locations')
        client_profile = ClientProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        client_profile.locations.add(*locations)
        return client_profile
```